# RAD Studio XE8 - You cannot set property. Instances of TCustomActionList are not found

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, rad-studio, c++builder-xe8

I've recently bought Embarcadero RAD Studio XE8 and started my first project. I am done with the setting up the UI, but when it came to adding actions to UI I'm in trouble because I am unable to access the Action section of the object inspector. It keeps saying "Instances of TCustomActionList are not found in the current units."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have most likely forgotten to drop a [`TActionList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ActnList.TActionList) or a [`TActionManager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ActnMan.TActionManager) component on the form; these are the `TCustomActionList` instances the error message is talking about.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The same way you drop a button or a list box or a memo on the form: using the component palette, probably on the bottom right side of the IDE. I don't remember if XE8 has a search box in that panel. If so, you can search for `TActionList`. Otherwise, you'll find it under "Standard".